# proving that an abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I do not understand the importance of the following information in the given problem: $$na = 0 ,\forall a \in A.$$

[image]

Now, in order to prove that A is a unitary $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$-module, since A is an abelian group it remains to prove the action of $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ on A. that is I want to prove that:

1-$\bar k (a + b) = \bar k a + \bar kb.$

2-$(\bar k + \bar s )a = \bar k a + \bar s a.$

3-$\bar k (\bar s a) = (\bar k \bar s)a.$

4-$ \bar 1 a = a.$

So, this is my proofs:

1. $l.h.s = \bar k.(a + b) = k(a + b)$(by the definition of the given action) $= ka + kb$ (multiplication is distributed over addition in $\mathbb{Z}$)= $\bar k.a + \bar k.b $ = r.h.s

2.$l.h.s = (\bar k + \bar s).a = \overline {k + s)}.a $( using the definition of the bar in $Z_{n}$)$ = (k+s)a = ka + sa = \bar k.a + \bar s.a = r.h.s $

3.$l.h.s = \bar k . (\bar s . a) = k (\bar s .a) = k(sa) = (ks) a = \overline{(ks)}.a = (\bar k \bar s).a =r.h.s $

4.$\bar 1.a = 1a =a$ (using that 1 is a multiplicative identity for $\mathbb{Z}$)

Are my proofs right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proofs look right but lack an important point: that the action is well defined.

You need to prove that $\bar k_1 = \bar k_2 \implies k_1 a = k_2 a$ for all $a$, so that the action of a residue class does not depend on the representative chosen in the definition.

Here is where you use the hypothesis $na=0$.

---

Here is an alternative proof (which is just the same proof in a different guise):

The action of $\mathbb Z$ on $A$ is equivalent to a ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb Z \to \operatorname{End}(A)$. Now if $\alpha \in \operatorname{End}(A)$, then $(n\alpha)(a)=\alpha(na)=\alpha(0)=0$ and so $\ker\phi \supseteq n\mathbb Z$. This gives $\bar\phi :\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z \to \operatorname{End}(A)$ and an action of $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z $ on $A$.

Comment: By this statement (which is just the same proof in a different guise) you mean the same as the proof of the action is well defined?

Comment: @Intuition, no the alternative proof is the whole thing.